# Hide table column when td rows are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Table:

```
<table cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" border = "1" width = "90%" class="table1">
    <tr >                    
        <th><b>Pos</b></th>
        <th><b>NICOMATIC P/N</b></th>
        <th><b>Client P/N</b></th>
        <th><b>ADD</b></th>
        <th><b>Quantity Ordered &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Requested Date &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Discount  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Unit Price</b></th>
        <!--<td><b>Discount</b></td>
        <td><b> &nbsp;</b></td>                          
        <td>Add</td> -->  
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!qouteLineItemMap}" var="qliRow" id="theQliRepeat">
    <apex:repeat value="{!qouteLineItemMap[qliRow]}" var="qli" id="therepeat1">
    <tr>
        <td><apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(rowNum)}" style="align:center;"/></td>
        <td class = "tdCustom" > <apex:outputfield value="{!qli.Name}"/><apex:inputfield value="{!qli.Or_Nicomatic_p_n__c}"/></td>
        <td class = "tdCustom" ><apex:outputField value="{!qli.Client_P_N__c}" /><apex:inputfield value="{!qli.Or_clientpn__c}"/></td>
        <td class = "tdCustom" >
        <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addBatch}" reRender="pb,errormsg" immediate="true">
        <apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" value="{!rowNum}" name="qliRowNum"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
        </td>
        <td class = "tdCustom" style="width:100px;">             
        <apex:repeat value="{!batchMap[qliRow]}" var="child" id="therepeat2">
        <table class="table-data" border = "1">
        <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="batchrowNum"/>
            <tr id="tr_clone">
                <td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.Quantity_Ordered__c}"  style="width:70px" required="true"/></td>
                <td> <apex:inputfield value="{!child.Requested_Date__c}"  style="width:90px" required="true"/></td> 
                <td> <apex:inputfield value="{!child.Discount__c}" style="width:40px" required="true"/></td>                       
                <td><apex:inputfield value="{!child.Unit_Price__c}"  style="width:110px" required="true"/></td>
                <td>
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteBatch}" reRender="pb,errormsg" id="deleteBatchid" immediate="true">
                <apex:param assignTo="{!qliRowNum}" name="deleteQlihRow" value="{!rowNum}"/>
                <apex:param assignTo="{!deleteBatchRow}" name="deleteBatchRow" value="{!batchrowNum}"/>
                </apex:commandButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <apex:variable var="batchrowNum" value="{!batchrowNum+ 1}"/>
        </table>
        </apex:repeat>
        </td> 
    </tr>
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum + 1}"/> 
    </apex:repeat>  
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
 $('.table1 tr th').each(function(i) {
        //select all tds in this column
        var tds = $(this).parents('table')
            .find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
        if(tds.is(':empty')) {
            //hide header
            $(this).hide();
            //hide cells
            tds.hide();
        } 
    }); 

</script>
```

intially

```
<th><b>Quantity Ordered &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Requested Date &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Discount  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Unit Price</b></th>
```

This column was empty .i want hide this when td was empty for entire column. I want to show the column when any one of the td is non empty .i had tried with the above code but it was not working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get your goal with this:

```
var tableRows = $('#table1 tr');
tableRows.eq(0).find('td:empty').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    console.log(index);
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    var isEmpty = true;
    tableRows.not($(this).parent()).find('td').eq(index).each( function() {
        console.log($(this));
        if(!$(this).is(':empty')) { isEmpty = false; }
    });
    if(isEmpty) { tableRows.each(function() { $(this).find('td').eq(index).hide() }); }
});
```

Working example:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehLscb69/)

Comment: Oh wait I see the problem, change the selection type: `var tableRows = $('table.table1 tr');` does that work for you?